# Issue with Meteor.loginWithGoogle

Tags: meteor

I am experiencing a strange issue with the Meteor Accounts package. More specifically, it's related to the Meteor.loginWithGoogle method. I have had this method working flawlessly in the past, until I recently upgraded to 0.9.3.1 from 0.8.3 (I think it was 0.8.3 anyways).

Now, All I am seeing is the not very helpful error message "No matching login attempt found". I have tried digging deeper into the issue, but I find that I don't know enough about the internals of the Accounts package to debug this in a meaningful way.

If anybody can offer any input at all, I would greatly appreciate it. My app is set to go live in about a week, and not being able to log in would greatly reduce the usefulness of the app ;-)

Comment: Just updated to Meteor 0.9.4, and the issue mysteriously disappeared. Make me both happy and sad. Happy because I don't have to battle with that issue anymore, and sad because I really wish I knew what was wrong. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment to the issue description, the issue went away when I upgraded to Meteor 0.9.4.